# Image creator PHP Script

Tags: images, php, image-editor, jquery

I am looking for a PHP Script that can do the following:

- Click and drag vector parts from a custom libary
- Saving the creation to an image file and a database (Mysql)
- Has to be a PHP script, can be with e.g. Jquery
- Can edit existing creations

[Something like this, but then with click and drag](http://codecanyon.net/item/svg-avatars-generator-jquery-integrated-script/6498300)